# Accessibility service не вызывается onServiceConnected

Tags: android, service, android-service

Пытаюсь реализовать сервис, реагирующий на касание экрана, но не получается запустить его.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service android:name=".KeyRecordService"
        android:label="@string/accessibility_service_label"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/serviceconfig" />
    </service>
```

KeyRecordService.java:

```
public class KeyRecordService extends AccessibilityService
{
   @Override
   public void onServiceConnected()
   {
        Log.d(Config.KEY_LOG_TAG, "KeyRecordService service started");
   }
...
}
```

serviceconfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
android:packageNames=""
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
android:notificationTimeout="100"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true"
android:settingsActivity="" />
```

Запуск сервиса из MainActivity:

```
private void StartKeyLogger()
{
    Log.d(Config.MAIN_TAG, "[Starting keylogger]");
    try
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, KeyRecordService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.d(Config.MAIN_TAG, "Error setting key logging service");
    }
}
```

Получаю следующий вывод в Logcat:

```
D/MainActivity: [Starting keylogger]
```

Соответственно, на касания экрана реакции тоже нет

Answer (score 0):

Небольшая часть [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService):

> The lifecycle of an accessibility service is managed exclusively by
> the system and follows the established service life cycle. Starting an
> accessibility service is triggered exclusively by the user explicitly
> turning the service on in device settings.

Жизненым циклом подобного `service` управляет исключительно система на основе настроек выбраных пользователем. Скорее всего у вас такие настройки не активны.